# GUI Wallet balance = 0 although wallet is synchronised and Daemon is synchronized (2240487) using Remote node

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cold-storage, wallet-recovery, balance

Please help! I didn't check my Monero account for a while and now I am unable to login to my GUI wallet anymore. After researching the issue, I decided to delete everything related to Monero on my MacOS computer and to start from scratch.

1. Downloaded and installed latest GUI version: 0.17.1.5-96f9c11 (Qt 5.12.8), embedded Monero version: 0.17.1.5-96f9c1132
2. Updated Ledger Nano X with latest firmware
3. Reinstalled XRM on Leger Nano X
4. Restored a new GUI wallet from Leger Nano X
5. Set wallet restore heights to: 1940000
6. Used remote node 'node.xmrbackb.one', Port 18081

After synchronizing for a while, I received:
Wallet is synchronized
Daemon is synchronized (2240502)
Network status: Remote node
Total balance: 0
Total unlocked balance: 0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already verified that the address is correct? Also, how did you initially fund this wallet?